# I want to implement a linq expression that will allow me to test an property on a supplied object

Tags: c#, linq, expression, moq

I want to implement this method from MOQ.  (Little out of my depth here)

```
    ISetup<T> Setup(Expression<Action<T>> expression);


    public class Foo {
        public string Bar { get; set; }
        public int Baz { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyCoolClass
    {
        public ?  Evaluate<Expression<Action>>(expression);
        //I want to be able to access and test the value of Foo.Bar (see below)
    }

    public class ClientOfMyClass
    {
        public void UseTheMethod()
        {
            MyCoolClass myCool = new MyCoolClass();
            bool result = myCool.Evaluate<Foo>(f => f.Bar);
        }
    }
```

Basically, I am trying to write a method that will allow the caller to specify a property on an object with an expression, and allow me to test the value of that property and do something with it.

Comment: How can we help? Do you have a question? Have you read [ask]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use an `Expression<Func<>>` parameter, and check that it contains a `Body`, and a `Member` of type `PropertyInfo`, and use `GetValue()` passing your object in.

```
public static void Evaluate<TObj,TProp>(
    this TObj obj, 
    Expression<Func<TObj, TProp>> expr)
{
    var prop = (expr.Body as MemberExpression)?.Member as PropertyInfo;
    var val = prop?.GetValue(obj);
    if (val != null) {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Note that the above code requires the passed in lambda to point to a Property. If you want to handle Fields as well as Methods, they will come in as different types of Expressions, and you'll want to handle handle them slightly differently.  For more context and usage, [here's a Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rmBXIh).

Edit: Updated to work with other property types.

Comment: Very close.  This works if the parameter is a string, but the cast to MemberExpression fails for anything else.  
ValidationError Evaluate<T, TProperty>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> propertyLambda) works in all cases.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, it only works for `object` properties (string happens to also be an object). I'll update the answer